# If $f$ continuous and $\lim_{x\to-\infty }f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty }f(x)=+\infty $ then $f$ takes its minimum.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ continuous and $$\lim_{x\to-\infty }f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty }f(x)=+\infty$$ then $f$ takes its minimum. This is a homework. My solution looks to simple, that's why I would like to have confirmation if it's correct or not.

**My attempts**

Let $a,b\in\mathbb R$, $a<b$. Let denote $M$ the maximum of $f$ on $[a,b]$. By definition of the limits, there is $N_1<a$ and $N_2>b$ such that $f(x)\geq M$ when $x<N_1$ and $x>N_2$. If $f(x)\geq M$ for all $x\in [N_1,N_2]$, then $M$ is the minimum. Otherwise, $f$ takes its minimum on $[N_1,N_2]$ (since $f$ is continuous on the compact $[N_1,N_2]$), and it's a global minimum.

Do you think it's correct ?

Comment: It's correct, but i think that when you say  $M$ is a maximum you really mean $M$ is a minimum.

Comment: Thank you. No, I really mean it's a maximum. But you are right, we can say that $M$ is a minimum, the proof will be the same (and it would be more logical) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct. You can simplify it a bit by starting with
a single point instead of an interval.
Also it is not necessary to distinguish whether
$f(x)\geq M$ for all $x\in [N_1,N_2]$ or not:

Let $a \in \mathbb R$ and $M := f(a)$. There exist $N_1 < a$ and $N_2 > a$
such that $f(x) \ge M$ for $x < N_1$ and for $x > N_2$. 
$f$ takes a minimum $m$ on the compact interval $[N_1, N_2]$. Since $m \le f(a) = M$, this
is also a global minimum.