# Prove that there is a number $y$ for which $y^n+f(y) \leq x^n+f(x)$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $f$ is a continuous function over reals and $n$ is a positive integer, for which  $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{x^n} =  \displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{x^n}= 0$. Prove that if $n$ is even, there is a number $y$ for which $y^n+f(y) \leq x^n+f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

This is a follow up question to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666191/prove-that-if-n-is-odd-then-there-is-an-x-for-which-fx-xn?noredirect=1#1666223) question. I am wondering if this would best be proved indirectly by assuming there doesn't exist such a $y$ as before. I tried indirectly and said that either $y^n + f(y) = x^n+f(x)$ or $y^n+f(y) \geq x^n+f(x)$ (by intermediate value theorem). How do I show a contradiction here?

Comment: Is there any relation between $x$ and $y$, such as $x < y$? Otherwise, if $y^n+f(y) > x^n+f(x)$ then you could just swap them. Or do you mean for *every* $x$ there is a $y$ such that ... ?

Comment: Yes, I just fixed that sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$g(x) := f(x) + x^n$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$, and for $x \ne 0$,
$$
 g(x) = f(x) + x^n = \bigl( \frac {f(x)}{x^n} + 1 \big) x^n \, .
$$
Since $f(x)/x^n \to 0$ for $x \to \pm \infty$, and $n$ is even,
it follows that
$$
 \lim_{x \to - \infty} g(x)  =  \lim_{x \to  \infty} g(x) = \infty \, .
$$

Therefore $g$ has a *global minimum* which is taken at some  point $y \in \Bbb R$ (see e.g. [If $f$ continuous and $\lim_{x\to-\infty }f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty }f(x)=+\infty $ then $f$ takes its minimum.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508344/if-f-continuous-and-lim-x-to-infty-fx-lim-x-to-infty-fx-infty)):
$$
  f(y) + y^n = g(y) \le g(x) = f(x) + x^n \text{ for all } x \in \Bbb R
$$